# Submit an HTML select/dropdown form to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am trying to submit an HTML `<form>` and have the `input` and `select` information entered into a MySQL database table. My code is entering the `<input type="text">` data into the table, but it is not entering the data in the `<select>`.

This is the `<form>` I have been using:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="send.php" method="post">
    <select name="gender">
        <option value="Male"> Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

And this is the PHP I've been using to enter the form into the table:

```
<?php
$gender=$_POST['gender']; // This is the select/dropdown
$name=$_POST['name'];  // This is the text input

mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('$gender', '$name')") ; 
?>
```

Comment: See: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Haha, the cartoon Joe linked to is great. Anywho, do not insert $_POST (or any user-entered data) directly into a mysql statement. That opens some big security holes. Look into the method [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). It's not perfect, but is a start. That aside, more information is needed to understand why your data isn't getting into the table. Is mysql throwing any errors? Use [print_r](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to make sure you are capturing data from the form correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...If that doesn't work try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('".$gender."','".$name."');");
```

Comment: you should avoid using concatenation in queries

Answer (score 2):

- try to print your form results
- try to print your SQL statement instead of executing
- check the statement by eye
- copy the statement and try to execute in at the server manually.
- add the `log=query.log` option in the `[mysqld]` section of MySQL server configuration file (probably `my.cnf`), restart the server and look into `query.log` for recent queries -- do they reach the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` (genderCol,nameCol) VALUES ('{$gender}','{$name}')");
```

Though, as @Joe Stefanelli stated, you should really be sanitizing input -- never trust the user. Take a look at using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your can try

```
<?php
$gender=$_POST['gender']; 
$name=$_POST['name']; 

mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` SET `fieldgender`='{$gender}', `fieldname`='{$name}'") ; 
?>
```

With fieldgender And fieldname is colums in your mysql table1